# How to create a temporary table in presto sql?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Is there any functionality to create a temporary table in presto SQL? Can't seem to find it in the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table-as.html) . Otherwise, is the best option just to create a regular table and drop it immediately after?

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything -- there is no CREATE TEMP TABLE that automagically destroys the object based on session scope, etc.

Your idea is a good one. Another approach that some folks take is using the in-memory connector for this work. YMMV since that connector isn't super-robust.